# Automatically resizing a window in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

edit:  I'm not sure how to get the stacktrace.  Here's the error I get:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$1(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Grid hgap=0.0, vgap=0.0, alignment=TOP_LEFTis already inside a scene-graph and cannot be set as root
    at javafx.scene.Scene$9.invalidated(Scene.java:1100)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:111)
    at javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.setRoot(Scene.java:1072)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:347)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.<init>(Scene.java:223)
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:108)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application application.Main
```

I have an assignment where I need to read in information and create a graph from it. It also needs to automatically resize a graph when the user drags the window. I've got the graph working but can't figure out how to get it resize.

I found a different thread that used something like this:

```
         StackPane root = new StackPane(pane);
         root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

//       use gridPane size to determine the factor to scale by
         NumberBinding maxScale = Bindings.min(root.widthProperty().divide(350),
                                              root.heightProperty().divide(100));
         pane.scaleXProperty().bind(maxScale);
         pane.scaleYProperty().bind(maxScale);
```

but that gave me a runtime error.

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.NumberBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;



public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {


        GridPane pane = new GridPane(); 
        
        pane.setMinSize(400, 500);
        pane.setMaxSize(350, 10000);

         StackPane root = new StackPane(pane);

        
        ArrayList <Team> aT =  new ArrayList <Team>();
        Scanner scannerIOInput = null;
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BorderPane root2 = new BorderPane();

        try{

            fis = new FileInputStream(new File("mp3_hockey_stats.txt"));
            scannerIOInput = new Scanner(fis);
//          System.out.println("File is read in");

            String c = null;
            int indx;
            
            
            //read in data 
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        
                    c = scannerIOInput.nextLine();
                    
                    indx = c.indexOf(",");

                    if (indx > 0)
                    {
                        String name = c.substring(0, indx);
                        String s1 = c.substring(indx + 1);
                        int stat = Integer.parseInt(s1);
                        aT.add(new Team (name, stat));
                        
                    }                           
                        
            }
            
            
            //print data
            
        
            
            int recX, recY, recWidth, recHeight;
            recX = 10;
            recY = 10;
            recWidth = 10;
            recHeight = 10;

            for (int i = 0; i < aT.size(); i++)
            {   
                
                Label name = new Label (aT.get(i).teamName1);
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle();
                r.setX(recX);
                r.setY(recY + (i * 100));
                r.setWidth(aT.get(i).stats1);
                r.setHeight(recHeight);
                r.setFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET);
        
                pane.add(name, 1, i);
                pane.add(r, 2, i);
                //pane.add(" ", 1, i+1);
                
            }
            
                        
            Scene scene = new Scene(pane,350, 100);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hockey Statistics Chart");
            primaryStage.show();

        
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)   {
            System.out.println("File not found.");

        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            System.out.println("NullPointerException.");
         
        }catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            
            System.out.println("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.");
            
        }catch (RuntimeException e){
            
            System.out.println("Runtime exception.");
            
        } finally {
            scannerIOInput.close();
        }
    
}



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace caused by the RuntimeException to your original post. This will help with answering your question.

Comment: [mcve] please ..